# How to change the decimal format from dot to comma when reading parquet files?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, parquet

I'm working with parquet files and in order to read them I'm using `pd.read_parquet()`. However, the numerical values in the file are using commas and it is misunderstanding the numbers.

How can I change the decimal sign from dot to comma?

Here my piece of code:

```
new_col = pa.parquet.read_table(filepath).to_pandas()
aux = pd.concat([aux, new_col])

df.head()

                      X_Principal  Y_Principal  value_main  \
ts                                                                     
2016-01-27 15:15:00             1.0             4.0        11.020800   
2016-01-27 15:15:00             1.0             4.0        11.020800   
2016-01-27 15:15:00             1.0             4.0        36.408001   
2016-01-27 15:15:00             1.0             4.0        36.408001   
2016-01-27 15:30:00             1.0             4.0        12.004800 

type(new_col)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

The number on the column value should be something like 110.20800, for example.

Comment: Do you really mean that decimals in your file are both commas and dots?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thank you so much for questionning. It is not really. Only commas and I want to change to dots.

Comment: what prevents you from reading your parquet file "as is" and changing decimals then from commas to points and casting objects to floats. Are you having any errors while reading parquet?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I have no error beyond the numbers all incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do some minimal reproducible experiment.

**Let's prepare some data:**

```
In [1]: df = pd .DataFrame({"a":["1,1", "1,2"],"b":[1,2]})                                                         

In [2]: df.to_parquet("./df.parquet", compression="GZIP")
```

**Let's check what do we have indeed:**

```
18:48:29 delete$ parquet-cat df.parquet 
a = 1,1
b = 1

a = 1,2
b = 2
```

**Then, let's read the data and cast column of concern to float:**

```
In [8]: df1 = pd.read_parquet("./df.parquet")                                                                                          

In [9]: df1                                                                                                                            
Out[9]: 
     a  b
0  1,1  1
1  1,2  2

In [10]: df1.a.str.replace(",",".").astype("float64")                                                                                  
Out[10]: 
0    1.1
1    1.2
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, it's working on a parquet file with comma decimals.

PS

The data you added to your question does not quite coincide with the question itself. I think you should investigate closer what you have in parquet file, with tools like `parquet-tool` and if it reads correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is a binary file format. Your parquet has stored floating point numbers as strings with a comma as a separator. So the format is already *wrong* in your parquet file, there is no space for interpretation (i.e. pandas does not "misunderstand" anything).

You can parse the column containing string representations of numericals with the comma as decimal separator yourself, e.g.

```py
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`.

Comment: what does `df['col'].dtype` give?

Comment: It gives: `float32`

Comment: Can you show your original code and also demonstrate what is the issue?

Comment: The original is just without your line. It gives a dataset but all numbers changed. I've have this problem before using csv, but pd.read_csv gives the option to change it, parquet doesn't.

Comment: OK, so if your column is of dtype float32, I do not understand your problem. Can you demonstrate what is your exact issue, e.g. by providing some more output, e.g. `df.dtypes` and `df.head()`?